# Type 'X' is not assignable to type 'Operation'

Tags: angular, typescript

Type 'Operation.GetList' is not assignable to type 'Operation'.

this is my error

```
private async getPermissions()  {
        const res = await this._entityRepository.sendRequest(this._globals.apiUrl, {
            key: 'Permission',
            operation: Operation.GetList

        });
```

error is Type 
'Operation.GetList' is not assignable to type 'Operation'.ts(2322)
data-request.model.ts(5, 12): The expected type comes from property 'operation' which is declared here on type 'DataRequestModel'

This is my data-request.model.ts

```
import { Operation } from '../enums';

export class DataRequestModel {
    public key?: string;
    public operation: Operation;
    public json?: string;
    public predicate?: string;
    public includes?: Array<string>;
    public page?: number;
    public pageSize?: number;
    public orderColumn?: string;
    public orderDirection?: string;
    public startIndex?: number;
    public count?: number;
    public query?: string;
    public ignoreQueryFilters?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I thin the getList method return an array of operations and if that correct you need to edit the operation proprety in your class to an array of operations

Comment: Can you show us the `Operation` enum.